# multiple plupload instances with common config

Tags: plupload

I have a page where I am using plupload to submit files to the server. I have multiple instances of plupload for different sections e.g. one for image files, one for videos, etc.

I would like to share some of the configuration options between both uploaders, while changing a few to suit the filetype. Specifically, the filters setting for the uploader.

I configure the general settings like so:

```
function init_uploaders()
{
    jQuery('.plupload').pluploadQueue({
    // General settings
    url: wpModelsL10n.url,
    runtimes : 'html5,gears,silverlight,flash',
    chunk_size: '1mb',
    max_file_size : '600mb',
    multiple_queues: true,
    multipart_params: {
        post_id: wpModelsL10n.post_id,
        post_type: wpModelsL10n.post_type,
        action: 'wp_models_media_upload',
        nonce: wpModelsL10n.nonce
    },
    // Flash settings
    flash_swf_url : _wpPluploadSettings.defaults.flash_swf_url, 
    // Silverlight settings
    silverlight_xap_url : _wpPluploadSettings.defaults.silverlight_xap_url,
}); 
}
```

I then create a separate uploader as follows:

```
function wp_models_init_uploader_pics()
{
    var pics_uploader = jQuery(".wp-models-pics-uploader").pluploadQueue();

    jQuery.extend(pics_uploader.settings.filters, 
    {
        title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"
    });
}
```

However, the uploader will still allow zip files to be added to the queue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Forgot the square brackets. Now all works as expected. See below: 

`function wp_models_init_uploader_pics()
{
var pics_uploader = jQuery(".wp-models-pics-uploader").pluploadQueue();
jQuery.extend(pics_uploader.settings.filters,
[{
title : "Image files", extensions : "jpg,gif,png"
}]);
}`